# How to do a linear probability model in R w/o constant

Tags: r, binary, linear-regression, probability

I have at least two periods: years t and t+1. I have defined income groups, e.g., different quartiles (Q1_t, Q2_t, Q3_t and Q4_t ) in terms of HH income distribution. of year t. Each Qx_t is a dummy {0,1} indicating if a HH is in this group {x= 1, 2, ... 4} in year t.
I would like to assess transition probabilities by estimating, e.g., the following equation [w/o constant!]

Q1_{t+1} = b1 Q1_t + b2 Q2_t + b3 Q2_t + b4 Q4_t + c X + e

on the LHS I would have a dummy indicating e.g. if a HH belongs into quartile 1 in year t+1. on the RHS I would have the four group dummies from year t plus a control vector X.

I would like to estimate this equation with a linear probability model (=OLS applied on binary data) in R.

I am doinglm(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2 + ...) but I am getting the following error:

```
model2<-lm(qt2~0+q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+n_female,n_male, data = df)
Error incontrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

This is a sample of my data.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(320, 300, 150, 170, 420, 430),size = c(5,1,6,3,4,2), n_fem = c( 2,1,3,3,2,1), n_male= c(3,0,3,1,2,1),n_sec= c (0,0,4,2,0,0),n_high= c(0,0,1,1,4,2), q1= c(1,0,0,0,0,0), q2=c(0,0,1,0,0,0), q3=c(0,0,0,1,0,1), q4=c(0,1,0,0,0,0),q5= c(0,0,0,0,0,0), qt1= c(1,0,0,0,0,0), qt2= c(0,0,0,1,0,0), qt3= c(0,0,0,0,0,1),qt4= c(0,0,0,0,1,0), qt5= c(0,0,0,0,0,0) 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))

ID   Size  n_fem n_male n_Sec n_High Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Qt1 QT2 QT3 QT4 QT5
320   5      2      3     0    0      1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0 
300   1      1      0     0    0      0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
150   6      3      3     4    1      0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
170   3      3      1     2    1      0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
420   4      2      2     0    4      0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
430   2      1      1     0    2      0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: If you put `+ 0` in a model formula, it will fit the model without an intercept. Do you need more help than that? If so, it would help a lot if you shared a sample of data and your code so far so we know where you're starting from.

Comment: I am running the following model: lm(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2 + ...)y is numeric as I read I have to converted in numeric and X1,X2... are factor variables with 1,0 or NA. and I get the following error: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: should I convert all to numeric?

Comment: If the data is binary 0/1 (and NAs), there shouldn't really be a difference between factor and numeric. The error you get suggests that when rows with NA are omitted, some of your variables are either ALL 1s or ALL 0s - and that's the issue causing the error. You can try something like `data_no_nas = na.omit(your_data)` and `sapply(data_no_nas, function(x) length(unique(x)))` to see the number of unique values by column in your data with the rows with missing values omitted. You may need to drop columns with high missingness so that you have enough data left after omitting missing values.

Comment: thank you! I have eliminated the NA from the variables in the model so there are just 0 or 1 (whether if they belong to the quintile or not). But I am still getting the same error....any ideas?

Comment: As my previous comment was trying to say,  the issue is probably that when you filter out the NAs, some of the variables that are either ALL 1s or ALL 0s in the remaining rows. You can't model variables that have only one value. The code in my last comment will help you figure out which variables those are.

Comment: I did sapply(data_no_nas, function(x) length(unique(x))) and all the variables in the model have 2 values.

Comment: I'm not really sure then - `lm` seems to think that some of the variables don't have 2 values. For more help you could ask a new question on this topic and include a sample of your data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question with a sample of the data

Comment: There are a few syntax errors - your `dput` is missing a comma at the end of the first line, and missing a `)` at the very end. Then your `lm` syntax is off - you use `n_female` where you need `n_fem`, and you need to use a `+` for `n_male`, not a `,`. After fixing those issues, the model runs just fine, so the data doesn't actually illustrate the problem. Can you fix syntax issues and find a subset of data that does illustrate the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, you just want:

`lm(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2 + ...)` or `glm(y ~ 0 + x1 + x2 + ..., family = binomial())` if you're looking for a logit model